# Unpacking lists of dicts column-wise with unique names in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

Suppose I have `df` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [
    [{'X': 'x1', 'Y': 'y1'}],
    [{'X': 'x2', 'Y': 'y2'}, {'X': 'x3', 'Y': 'y3'}],
    []
]})

df
    A   B
0   a   [{'X': 'x1', 'Y': 'y1'}]
1   b   [{'X': 'x2', 'Y': 'y2'}, {'X': 'x3', 'Y': 'y3'}]
2   c   []
```

Column `B` includes `lists` of `dicts` that can be empty or include any number of `dicts`. Each dict will always include `X` and `Y` keys. What I want to do is to split these into columns. So the first `dict` will produce columns `X_0` and `Y_0`, and so on. In this example, the output would look like:

```
df
    A   X_0 Y_0 X_1 Y_1
0   a   x1  y1      
1   b   x2  y2  x3  y3
2   c
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use list comprehension with nested dictionary comprehension for list of dicts with new keys generated with `enumerate`, pass to `Dataframe` constructor and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original, also [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for extract column `B`:

```
L = [{f'{k}_{i}': v for i, y in enumerate(x) for k, v in y.items()} for x in df.pop('B')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
   A  X_0  Y_0  X_1  Y_1
0  a   x1   y1  NaN  NaN
1  b   x2   y2   x3   y3
2  c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [
    [{'X': 'x1', 'Y': 'y1'}],
    [{'X': 'x2', 'Y': 'y2'}, {'X': 'x3', 'Y': 'y3'}],
    np.nan
]})


L = [{f'{k}_{i}': v for i, y in enumerate(x) for k, v in y.items()} 
                   if isinstance(x, list)  
                   else {} for x in df.pop('B')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
   A  X_0  Y_0  X_1  Y_1
0  a   x1   y1  NaN  NaN
1  b   x2   y2   x3   y3
2  c  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: The real `df` has more columns than `A` and `B`. Does this answer hold in those cases as well?

Comment: @CHRD - Exactly, working well. Only ordering is different, new columns are added to end of all columns, e.g. if `A,B,C,D` columns then get `A,C,D, X_0, X_1...` columns

Comment: Ok thanks. I was wondering since running `L = [{f'{k}_{i}': v for i, y in enumerate(x) for k, v in y.items()} for x in df.pop('B')]` gives me `'float' object is not iterable`. Thought that might be the reason. Know why this could be the case? the `dtype` of column `B` is `object` (if that matters).

Comment: @CHRD - Is possible some missing values in `B` column? Is possible remove them by `df = df.dropna(subset=['B'])` ?

Comment: That seems to solve it. However, ideally I would not lose those observations since there might be values in the other columns which are of importance.

Comment: @CHRD - Give me some time.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: @CHRD - Answer was edited, if list, applied solution, else created empty dict.